# Displaying Bluetooth gadget's battery status on the phone

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life, notification-bar, bluetooth-pairing

I have a Bluetooth headset (BlueBuds X) which uses a battery. I want to know its battery status directly from the phone. I've looked everywhere and I cannot find a solution that isn't a scam.

Is it possible to display the battery percentage on the phone (preferably, on notification bar)?

Answer (score 10):

This is possible on Android, at least on Lollipop. The feature is dependent on the Bluetooth headset sending the battery level in the right format.

If the headset supports it, you will see an option in the settings screen for the Bluetooth device. The option will be right above the check-boxes for Call and Media audio. If you don't see this option, then the headset either doesn't send battery data or it doesn't send it in the correct format.

Once the feature is enabled, you will see a fill-able icon on the left side of your notification bar. I've confirmed this using a cheap earbud set from China.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as a device implements the Bluetooth [Battery Service (BAS)](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245138), it is able to indicate the battery status.

Answer (score 4):

For some headphones, in order to see the battery percentage you have to enable the "Calls" button or something similar to that in the Bluetooth settings of the device.

Answer (score 2):

Honor 20 pro - you have to enable "Calls" on bluetooth connection of the device, then the baterry shows up on status bar. "Media" checkbox is not enough :(

Answer (score 1):

When using my Sony SBH80 with my Z3, I simply use the the drop down notification screen which shows battery status in hours and standby life.

Answer (score 1):

With Android 8.0 (O) the fucationality has been added to AOSP [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/bluetooth-battery-level-indicators-android/)

Comment: The API has been added, but there's no GUI yet, so that doesn't help users looking for this feature. Possibly it will be added to the official release of O, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

On my pixel 2 Android 8.1 I connected [Shuhua headphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0739VQWJ2)... No UI for the headphones battery. The only way to see battery is to go to settings --> connected devices --> Bluetooth, then you see a battery level.

I installed [BatOn app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limi.baton).

Disclaimer: 
- not sure if these headphones support the battery level API
- there may be a way to display the Bluetooth battery without the BatOn app... But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I updated to Oreo a few days ago on my one plus 5 and to my pleasant surprise, I see that the battery status of my Bluetooth headphones is showing up. What a nice addition to have and something I was really jealous of from ios but I don't have any reason to buy an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

On Android no.
Some Bluetooth devices like your headset are able to report their battery status to phone but Android unlike iOS has not implemented that functionality in core system. Some vendors like Jabra or Platonic create their apps in Play Store, which show headset battery level on phobe but JarBirds didn't.

Comment: My LG G4 on Android Lollipop (5.1) shows the battery of a Matrix2 headset in the status bar with no additional apps. There's the possibility of some protocol incompatibility between iOS and Android, or some specific devices not supporting it, but it definitely works in at least one case.

Comment: It used to work on my LG G3 as well, with lollipop. I upgraded to Cyanogenmod 13 (marshmallow) and it stopped working! :( The headset I'm using is the mpow swift.

Comment: Wrong. Works fine in Android 5.1.1 for my August BT headphones out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The latest CM13 builds have added suport for this feature .. it works/acts/behave just like in iOS displaying a Little verticale bar next to the Bluetooth symbol in notificazione bar on the night. The best part, it works with my Jaybird BBX

Answer (score 0):

On stock android it's impossible due security reasons, battery level messages are blocked far beyond android sdk. Cyanogenmode for instance shows battery level without any problem. But you can try 3d-party apps like [Baton](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limi.baton), which tries to fill such functionality hole.

Comment: Why would "security" prevent this?